# In intellij idea, how config to make the files under the resource/ folder compiler to classes/config/ folder, not directly under classses/ folder

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ant

In intellij idea, how config to make the files under  the resource/ folder compiler to classes/config/ folder, not directly under  classses/ folder

Comment: you can config project structure (click File button -> Project Structure)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option would be to put them in a folder `resources/config/` rather than just `resources/`. Depending on what build framework you are using (maven, gradle etc) this would also provide consistent results.